# Data is not writing in the Bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like a realize registration but the data is not written into the bean. 
But the email data is correct in the other datatyps is a null.
I get a few warnings but I think the problem must be in the xhtml code.

I'm using
google-app engine
jsf 2.1
primefaces 3.5

Bean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "regiBean")
@SessionScoped
public class RegisterBean implements Serializable {

    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String repeatpassword;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private boolean gtc;
    private String locale;


    private static Map<String, Object> countries;

    static {
        countries = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        countries.put("German", Locale.GERMAN);
        countries.put("English", Locale.ENGLISH);

    }

    public RegisterBean() {
        super();
    }

    public RegisterBean(String email, String username, String password,
            String repeatpassword, String firstname, String lastname,
            boolean gtc) {
        super();
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.repeatpassword = repeatpassword;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.gtc = gtc;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRepeatpassword() {
        return repeatpassword;
    }

    public void setRepeatpassword(String repeatpassword) {
        this.repeatpassword = repeatpassword;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public boolean getGtc() {
        return gtc;
    }

    public void isGtc(boolean gtc) {
        this.gtc = gtc;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public void showDialog() {



        System.out.println("AUSGABE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!:  " + toString());

        //if(gtc == true)
        {
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("myDialog.show();");

        }

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RegisterBean [email=" + email + ", username=" + username
                + ", password=" + password + ", repeatpassword="
                + repeatpassword + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname="
                + lastname + ", gtc=" + gtc + "]";
    }

       //value change event listener
       public void localeChanged(ValueChangeEvent e){
          String newLocaleValue = e.getNewValue().toString();
          for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : countries.entrySet()) {
             if(entry.getValue().toString().equals(newLocaleValue)){
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                   .getViewRoot().setLocale((Locale)entry.getValue()); 

             }
          }
          FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
       }

}
```

register.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:body>

    <ui:composition template="/META-INF/templates/templateLogin.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="title">
              <h:outputText value="Register"/>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">

            <h:form id="regiForm">

                <p:panelGrid  >

                    <p:row style="height:20%">
                       <p:column> <h:outputLabel styleClass="col" for="mail" value="#{msg['regi_mail']}" />   </p:column>                                         
                       <p:column> 
                            <p:inputText style="width:350px"  validatorMessage="#{msg['regi_mail_valid']}"   id="email" value="#{regiBean.email}" required="true"  >
                                <f:validateRegex pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"/>
                                <f:ajax event="keyup" render="emailmessage username pic " execute="@this"   />           
                            </p:inputText>
                       </p:column>
                       <p:column><p:message for="email" id="emailmessage" /></p:column>
                    </p:row>

                    <p:row style="height:20%">
                        <p:column><h:outputLabel value="#{msg['regi_username']} " /></p:column>                
                        <p:column><h:outputLabel for="email"  style="#{facesContext.validationFailed ? 'display:inline;' : 'display:none;'};"    id="username" value="#{regiBean.email}" /> </p:column>
                        <p:column><p:graphicImage for="email" libary="images" name="ok.png" id="pic" style="#{not facesContext.validationFailed ? 'display:inline; color:green;' : 'display:none;'}"  /> </p:column>
                   </p:row>


                    <p:row style="height:20%">
                        <p:column><h:outputLabel  for="password" value="#{msg['regi_password']}" /></p:column>        
                        <p:column>
                            <p:password style="width:350px"     id="password"
                                    value="#{regiBean.password}" match="repeatpassword"
                                    feedback="true" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_password_error']}" validatorMessage="#{msg['regi_password_match']}"  />
                        </p:column>    
                        <p:column><p:message for="password"/></p:column>    
                    </p:row>


                    <p:row style="height:20%">
                        <p:column><h:outputLabel for="repeatpassword" value="#{msg['regi_reppassword']}" /></p:column>    
                        <p:column>
                            <p:password style="width:350px"     id="repeatpassword"
                                    value="#{regiBean.repeatpassword}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_password_error']}" validatorMessage="#{msg['regi_password_match']}" />
                        </p:column>    
                        <p:column><p:message for="repeatpassword"/></p:column>    
                     </p:row>



                    <p:row style="height:20%">
                        <p:column><h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="#{msg['regi_firstname']}" /></p:column>    
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText  style="width:350px"   id="firstname"
                                     value="#{regiBean.firstname}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_firstname_error']}" />                                 
                        </p:column>    
                        <p:column><p:message for="firstname"/></p:column>    
                     </p:row>

                    <p:row style="height:20%">
                        <p:column><h:outputLabel for="lastname" value="#{msg['regi_lastname']}" /></p:column>    
                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText style="width:350px"   id="lastname"
                                     value="#{regiBean.lastname}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_lastname_error']}" />
                        </p:column>    
                        <p:column><p:message for="lastname"/></p:column>    
                     </p:row>


                    <p:row style="height:20%">
                       <p:column> <h:outputLabel for="gtc" value="#{msg['regi_gtc']}" /></p:column>    
                       <p:column>
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="gtc" value="#{regiBean.gtc}" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['regi_gtc_error']}"  >
                                <f:validator validatorId="RequiredCheckboxValidator" />  
                            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox >
                       </p:column>    
                       <p:column><p:message for="gtc"/></p:column>    
                    </p:row>



                    <p:row style="height:20%">              
                        <p:column><h:outputText value="#{msg['regi_language']}"></h:outputText> </p:column>    
                        <p:column>
                            <h:selectOneMenu value="#{regiBean.locale}" onchange="submit()"
                                         valueChangeListener="#{regiBean.localeChanged}" immediate="true">  
                                <f:selectItems value="#{regiBean.countries}" />
                            </h:selectOneMenu>    
                        </p:column>   
                          <p:column></p:column>   
                     </p:row>

                    <p:row style="height:20%">           
                        <p:column><h:outputText/> </p:column>       

                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandButton style="width:350px"  type="submit"  actionListener="#{regiBean.showDialog}" id="ajax" 
                                         value="#{msg['regi_button']}" update="regiForm"   process="@this"/>
                        </p:column>  
                        <p:column></p:column>  
                      </p:row>  

                </p:panelGrid>
                   <p:dialog id="dialog" header="#{msg['regi_dialog_header']}" widgetVar="myDialog"  position="center center" >  
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg['regi_dialog']}" />  
                    </p:dialog>
            </h:form>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I know what is the warnings your getting

Comment: Can you show the template file? Also check for errors in the generated page using your browser's web development tool or firebug.

Comment: AUSGABE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!:  RegisterBean [email=franz.kienegger@htlpinkafeld.at, username=null, password=null, repeatpassword=null, firstname=null, lastname=null, gtc=false]
Dez 06, 2013 9:10:56 AM com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer getForComponent

Comment: How can i upload my Template Files?

Comment: What do you mean with SSCCE?

Comment: Hi BalusC
Why have you deleted your answer?